# How would I loop back to the start

Tags: console, calculator

I am really confused on loops; I am new to C# (I have only ever worked with assembly on 16 and 32 bit micro controllers).

any way I have this code:

```
    {


        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number");
            Decimal iNumber1;
            if (!Decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out iNumber1)) { Console.WriteLine("Enter a number dummy"); Console.Read(); return; }
            Decimal x = iNumber1;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number");
            Decimal y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 for addition");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 2 for subtration");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 3 for multification");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 4 for divition");
            int z = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (z)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine(x + y);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine(x - y);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine(x * y);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine(x / y);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

This is just a simple console app calculator; but I want to be able to loop back to the start if a number isn't entered.

Comment: Don't ever get in the habit of insulting your users, it will come back to bite you in the ass.

Comment: I wasn't aware that I was insulting users. What did I do?

Comment: You say `Enter a number dummy`

Comment: OH! This will never go public haha; just me trying to learn C. BUT! I have noted to be extra careful :)

Comment: So you think - but code you never expected to be public will be public some day - and then you'll be sorry

Comment: c#** that is. Well let's hope not anyways haha! Thanks for the reminders mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow you to run until Esc is pressed.

```
 while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
 {
  // your code
 }
```

Comment: This works well; but now I'm exiting the application if I do not enter a number; "Enter a number dummy!" pops up and i press enter again and the app closes. I would like it to loop back to the top again if there is no decimal entered.

Comment: while(!firstEntered){ Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number");
            Decimal iNumber1;
            try{(!Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), out iNumber1)) catch{ Console.WriteLine("Enter a number dummy"); }
            Decimal x = iNumber1; firstEntered = true;} this should give you idea on how to do all the others, it might not work as I am not used to code into edit field